# Radiobutton updates value but at the same time doesn't? (Python, Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

I'm quite new to Python and for training purposes I made myself a little program to document the outcome of a game a friend and I play from time to time.

Part of the interface are multiple radiobuttons. Here's two sets of buttons for my example. I excluded placements:

```
from tkinter import *

main = Tk()
main.title('Test')
main.geometry('400x270')

winner = StringVar()
winner.set("C")
condi = StringVar()
condi.set("")

def get_values():
    x = winner.get()
    y = condi.get()
    z = map_entry.get()
    print(x, y, z)

winner1_button = Radiobutton(main, indicatoron = 0, text="A", variable=winner, value="A")
winner2_button = Radiobutton(main, indicatoron = 0, text="B", variable=winner, value="B")
condi1_button = Radiobutton(main, indicatoron = 0, text="Victory", variable=condi, value="Victory")
condi2_button = Radiobutton(main, indicatoron = 0, text="Surrender", variable=condi, value="Surrender")
map_entry =  Entry(main, bd=5, width=20)

continue_button = Button(main, text="Continue", command=get_values)

test_label = Label(main, bg='#D5E88F', textvariable=winner)
test_label2 = Label(main, bg='#D5E88F', textvariable=condi)
```

Now: My problem is that the values of the respective variables do not seem to change as I hit a button - but at the same time, they do?

E.g.: The default value for "winner" is "C". Once I hit the button labeled "A", the value changes to "A". I implemented testlabels that show the respective value, so I know it updated. Then I'd like to get that value of "winner" into a function, doing that with winner.get(). The output of winner.get() however is still the default value "C" not "A".

Any input from Entry-Widgeds however work perfectly fine. It's just buttons and their values.

I already looked in the Internet for a solution but all I found were things I already know and did. Still it's not working tho. Any idea why?

Comment: It works fine, i.e. shows correct selections, in my Windows with Python 3.8.12.

Comment: Your code works fine for me. You clearly haven't posted a complete [mcve]. Perhaps there's more to your code than what you're showing.